# AWS Device Farm - Schedule Run - Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am hoping someone here has come across this issue and has an answer for me.

I have setup a project in device farm and have written automation tests in ***Appium using JS***.

When I create a run manually using the console the runs succeed without any issues and my tests get executed.

However when I try and schedule a run using the CLI using the following command it fails with an error

`aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn projectArn --app-arn appArn --device-pool-arn dpARN --name myTestRun --test type=APPIUM_NODE,testPackageArn="testPkgArn"`

***Error : An error occurred (ArgumentException) when calling the ScheduleRun operation: Standard Test environment is not supported for testType: APPIUM_NODE***

`Cli Versions : aws-cli/1.17.0 Python/3.8.1 Darwin/19.2.0 botocore/1.14.0`

Answer (score 0):

That is expected currently for the [standard environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-environments.html#test-environments-standard). The command will need to use the [custom environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-environments.html#custom-test-environment) which the cli can do by setting the testSpecArn value.

This arn is an upload in device farm consisting of a .yaml file which defines how the tests are executed.

This process is discussed here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-test-run.html#how-to-create-test-run-cli-step6

The error in this case is caused by the fact that the APPIUM_NODE test type can only be used with the custom environment currently.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However the documentation doesn't say anywhere that APPIUM_NODE belongs to a custom environment. Also how is this different to running it directly from the Device Farm GUI which works without any issues ?

Comment: You may be right there, I did not find it in the docs explicitly. The Device Farm web console is different than the command in the question because it will schedule the run using a testSpecArn of the yaml file to use with the custom environment if APPIUM_NODE is selected. That is why the CLI command fails. You may check CloudTrail to confirm the parameters sent.